# How can I create a punctilio for verifying path width in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

Spreadshirt design guidelines dictate that all lines and elements need to be a thickness of at least 1.5mm. They suggest you can verify this by:

> using a 1.5mm dot (punctilio) to mouse over the thinnest parts of your
>   design and 1.0mm circle to mouse over this space between the lines.

How can I achieve this in Illustrator CS6 Mac?

Additional info: I also need to do this with expanded type, not just single paths and shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stroke the shape typing in 1.5mm:

[image]

It will convert it to the correct pt size based on your ppi:

[image]

As far as the space between lines.. take the ellipse tool and click on the page without drawing an ellipse. You'll get a panel for entering exact values:

[image]

Enter in your 1mm values and you're left with a circle you can use to drag between thin sections to spot-check.

---

However it would seem for modern digital tools it might be easier to change your units in the preferences to `mm` and then draw a line between thin parts checking that way. Just undo the line or never release it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. What if the the 'shape' is actually an expanded type object e.g. the letter 'o'. This is a filled shape not a simple path so stroking it will increase the width.

Comment: @codecowboy Well there you have two options -- one would be planning for the increase in width when doing your design. Or two use the `Inside Stroke` which can be found on the Stroke Panel.